# Lost Focus of App In windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, lost-focus

Similar to Windows store Apps .How could i pause the game in windows phone 8.

In windows Store apps

```
Windows.Current.Activated = Activated;
```

For Windows Phone 8

```
   ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the `App.Deactivated` event to know when the user has left your application without closing it.